# What is going on at the top of this function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, initialization

I'm currently looking at a function example that I can't seem to figure out using MFC in Visual C++. The function is as follows

```
CMFC_OSG_MDIView::CMFC_OSG_MDIView() :mOSG(0L)
{
}
```

I understand everything here except the mOSG(0L) snippet. mOSG was declared in the MFC_OSG _MDIView class as follows:

```
cOSG* mOSG;
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for your helpful answers! I took C++ back in college, but don't remember hearing or reading anything about initializer lists. Thanks again for the prompt help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
CMFC_OSG_MDIView::CMFC_OSG_MDIView() :mOSG(0L)
{
}
```

The above is a constructor, for a class called `CMFC_OSG_MDIView`. `:mOSG(0L)` is called `initializer list`, which is executed when an object is created. The init-list gets called before the body of the constructor, and it is the *correct* place to initialize the member variables.

Answer (score 1):

That's an initializer - `mOSG` is initialized with 0L. When the control enters the constructor body `mOSG` is already initialized.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list) for discussion of why use initializers instead of assignment inside of the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

`0L` specifies a long integer with value zero. So this initializes the class member `mOSG` with 0.